# how to translate "insert into on conflict" from postgres to h2 merge

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I have a JDBC application that uses postgres INSERT INTO / ON CONFLICT to perform an upsert query.  We would like to support H2 as well, but H2 uses the MERGE query instead.  How would I go about translating the following query into H2's syntax?  The H2 code will be in a separate library, which means that it doesn't have to work in both postgres and H2.

```
INSERT INTO dest_table(id,
                     field1,
                     field2,
                     field3,
                     field4)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
on conflict (id) do update
set (field3,field3) = (excluded.field3, excluded.field4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as soon as I posted to StackOverflow I figured it out.  Here is my solution:

Table setup

```
drop table if exists characters;

CREATE TABLE characters (
    id int not null,
    first character varying(50),
    last character varying(50));

insert into characters (id, first, last) values ( 1, 'scooby', 'doo' );
insert into characters (id, first, last) values ( 2, 'eric', 'cartman' );
insert into characters (id, first, last) values ( 3, 'luke', 'skywalker' );

select * from characters;
-------------------------
1,scooby,doo
2,eric,cartman
3,luke,skywalker
```

The update query looks like this (with hardcoded values, but it should work with placeholders as well)

Insert (no conflict):

```
merge into characters
using values (4, 'darth', 'vader') as incoming(id,first,last)
on characters.id = incoming.id
when not matched then
    insert (id, first, last) values (incoming.id, incoming.first, incoming.last)
when matched then
    update set first = incoming.first, last = incoming.last;

select * from characters;
-------------------------
1,scooby,doo
2,eric,cartman
3,luke,skywalker
4,darth,vader
```

Update (conflict on 'id', just updates darth vader to anikan skywalker):

```
merge into characters
using values (4, 'anikan', 'skywalker') as incoming(id,first,last)
on characters.id = incoming.id
when not matched then
    insert (id, first, last) values (incoming.id, incoming.first, incoming.last)
when matched then
    update set first = incoming.first, last = incoming.last;

select * from characters;
-------------------------
1,scooby,doo
2,eric,cartman
3,luke,skywalker
4,anikan,skywalker
```